# How do I increase the height of drag and drop area in wdCalendar(JQuery Event Calendar Plugin)

Tags: php, jquery

Anybody familiar with **wdCalendar** ,a google look a like event calendar plugin in jquery .
I got this from http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/. 
I need to increase the drag and drop area of wdcaledar. I installed fresh copy from there site .it works well .But When  I  installed it to my site ,mine  have a header portion ,that takes 200px height ,then the draggabble area misplaced .So I cannot drag events to bottom area. I've  checked so many times in the code ,but couldn't find a good solution . Any explanation? Thanks!

Comment: dont know of books but you could search for spring mvc on google and find a few tutorials. it would be easiest to learn via tutorials i guess...

Comment: The problem with Java web programming is that things have gotten *hugely* complex/complicated. I can't recommend a book because I wouldn't know where to start. Best piece of survival advice I can give you: if any particular framework (e.g.: JSF) looks impossible to understand (e.g.: JSF), it probably is a waste of time (e.g.: JSF) and you should move on to another web framework (e.g.: not JSF).

Answer (score 2):

My advice, if you don't know java, **don't** start doing web application development. Web application development goes as far as designing the system or architecting your application.

As for web application framework, use the currently available Java EE web application framework, JSF. Again, there are tons of tutorials on the web on how to use JSF (even good blog by an avid SO geek, BalusC). This assumes you already have knowledge of Enterprise Application, such as Servlet.

You will have to start from the beginning, like all of us did: understand Servlet and Filters, as every web application framework, including REST frameworks are built on top of it. You will need to.

Start writing a simple servlet web application and once you understand Servlet, move to MVC type framework, such as Struts, or jump to Component-based MVC such as JSF.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Oracle's official tutorial:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for "freely available" but I'm going to highly recommend the [java certification](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_exam_id=1Z0_851) as a way to get a develop a good all round understanding of the core language. The certification book is excellent, and the certification itself will provide you with a learning goal, even if you are not really that interested in the piece of paper(which I wasn't).

I feel that it's very important to have an understanding of the core before trying to embark on the many other facets provided by the Java architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think yo have to first start with core java then move to advance. you may refer headfirst of java.

Answer (score 0):

A good introductory book is

"Head First Servlets & JSP - passing the sun certified web component developer exam." from O'Rielly

It starts right from the basics, I wish I'd known about it when I started out. Although there is a lot of stuff on the web, a lot of it is basic to the point of being dangerous and you cna end up structuring your applications very poorly.

I'd also recommend getting some Jave experience first, just try writing a few that output text to the console.